# How to provide a restart count to systemd service

Tags: embedded-linux, systemd

I have an embedded device which manages its various services using systemd.  Our status reporting application is one of these services.  It is always on and it automatically restarts on failure (crashes, exceptions, OOM conditions, whatever).

We report an event to our cloud services on device restart (technically application restart) but I'd like to distinguish first start (after reboot) from restart.  Is there a mechanism built into systemd which can provide the service restart count, or do I need to roll my own method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the journal ? If you do, then you can get the count like this:

```
journalctl -b -u myservicename.service |grep -c Started
```

The -b option limits logs to the current boot; -u limits to the service in argument.

Then you grep for the "Started" line, and tell grep to only give you the number of matches.

Comment: I happen to have "Started" in my other logs generated from the service, but with minor adjustments this is a reasonable approach to rolling my own method

Answer (score 3):

you can use following command:

```
systemctl show foo.service -p NRestarts
```

It will return a value if the service is in a restart loop, otherwise, will return nothing.

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post. This provided answer may be correct, but **it could benefit from an explanation**. Code only answers are not considered "good" answers. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review).

Comment: This feature was added shortly after (two months, I think) this question was originally asked and answered.  While this is now the most correct answer (and I've upvoted it) the accepted one was the most helpful at the time.